# Unity - Parent with children fall apart

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a player character, made of some cubes, spheres and a capsule. I created the empty object `Player` and all body parts of the player are a child of `Player`. I have two planes, with a moving platform in between. I can walk and jump on the normal planes and the walls, but when the player is on the moving platform the bodyparts of the player fall apart. Maybe it's something really stupid, but I just started with Unity.

This is what goes wrong, the player falls apart on the moving platform: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/207s3sz/9

And below the information about the overview, the player, the body parts, and the moving platform with according character-holder. All bodyparts have the same properties as the `body` part on the screenshot. Can anyone help me with what goes wrong here? How can I transport the whole player by the moving platform?

[image]

[image]

HoldCharacter script:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HoldCharacter : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        other.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;                        
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        other.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happen if if you remove the `is Trigger` from the character holder? why do you need 2 colliders nested that's `MovingPlatform -> characterHolder`? what happens if you replace your `CapsuleCollider` on your `Body` to be a `BoxCollider`?... I had issues before with collisions between different types of colliders.

Comment: Can you show your HoldCharacter script?

Comment: When I disable 'is trigger' I can stand on the moving platform, is doesn't fall apart, but when the platform moves the player doesn't stay on the platform and falls down. I used the nested 'Moving Platform and CharacterHolder' because I saw that in a YouTube video. But when I only use one feet and jump on the platform, it works. So the combination 'platform-feet' works, but the other parts of the body 'release'. Only on this moving platform. @DavidEspino

Comment: I added the HoldCharacter script to the question! :) @SergiyKlimkov

Comment: so how Is Trigger works is that... it will fire `OnTriggerExit` and `OnTriggerEnter`, but it will let the object `go through` it. If you disable the `IsTrigger`, then you need to move the logic to `OnCollisionEnter` on `OnCollisionExit` methods. If the `isTrigger` uncheck kind of worked, maybe is just the fact that you move the logic for `HoldCharacter` to `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionEnd` respectively.

Comment: Sorry I think I explained wrong what happens when I disable the trigger of the HoldCharacter. When I disable trigger, I can stand on the moving platform, and the player doesn't fall apart. But when the moving platform moves to the other side, the player keeps on the same position, and falls down by gravity when the platform on which he stood is gone. So, it doesn't let the object go through it, but the object doesn't move with the platform and falls down when the platform moved away @DavidEspino

Comment: yes... I think it's because the `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnTriggerExit` on your HoldCharacter MonoBehavior ... replace the `HoldCharacter`code by this

```void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo) {
        collisionInfo.gameObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;


    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        collisionInfo.gameObject.transform.parent = null;
    }```

worth to give a shot

Comment: However, I tried to change the OnTrigger parts to OnCollision in the script, and indeed, that worked! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Niceeee!!!... any thumbs up would be appreciated :)

Comment: Yes I already wanted to, but because this were comments, I voted them as a usual comment. (No 'answer' I can accept or give a thumb up). I didn't see a thumb up button. But if you say the same in an answer now, I can accept it and thumb up :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154394/discussion-between-david-espino-and-lakeviking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to disable the `isTrigger` flag. Here are some insights

so how Is Trigger works is that... it will fire `OnTriggerExit` and `OnTriggerEnter`, but it will let the object go through it. If you disable the `IsTrigger`, then you need to move the logic to `OnCollisionEnter` on `OnCollisionExit` methods. If the isTrigger uncheck kind of worked, maybe is just the fact that you move the logic for HoldCharacter to `OnCollisionEnter` and `OnCollisionEnd` respectively Like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo) { 
   collisionInfo.gameObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform; 
} 
void OnCollisionExit(Collision collisionInfo) {
    collisionInfo.gameObject.transform.parent = null; 
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, the children of objects with Rigidbodys have physics as well. Maybe put the rigidbody on a child of the player, like so.

Player
-head
-arms
-legs
-empty gameobject with rigidbody

Comment: Do you mean removing the rigidbody of the parent, and add a rigidbody to all child objects? When I try this, the object falls apart on the 'starting floor'. Or do you mean 'creating an empty game object, give it a rigidbody, and add it as a child to the player? And remove the rigidbody of the parent player?' Then I can't jump anymore, and I can walk through walls. Or don't I understand what you mean?